# Detrend Flux Time Series with Non-Linear Trend

Tags: python, numpy

I am needing to detrend flux time series data (light curves), but I'm running into a problem when the time series data doesn't have a simple linear trend.

I've been using scipy.signal.detrend() for the detrending of linear cases, but that isn't sufficient here.

I've used numpy.polyfit() to attempt polynomial detrending, but I'm not sure what to do with the polynomial coefficients it returns.

Can someone advise me as to the next intelligent step to take?  Or, if someone has a better method for detrending non-linear data, I'd be delighted to hear that as well.

Comment: On a random note, the rash of "too broad" close votes is getting really problematic.  How in the world is a question specifically about how to apply `numpy.polyfit` and `numpy.polyval` to detrend data "too broad"?  It's not a bad question, and it's very specific. However, you could improve it a bit by including specific code snippets.

Comment: @JoeKington I'm not inclined to include actual pieces of my code, as they are part of my research and are not something I can give out at present.  However, the following is basically the spirit of what I've done:  flux_no_nans = net_flux[~np.isnan(net_flux)] is what I have used to remove the NaNs from my data, with net_flux being the array of flux values.  time_no_nans = time_array[~np.isnan(net_flux)]  is the corresponding time array.

Comment: For linear trends, I have used detrended_flux = scipy.signal.detrend(flux_no_nans).  For non-linear trends, I have tried poly_detrend = np.polyfit(time_no_nans, flux_no_nans, deg = 2), changing the degree to see what effect it would have.

Comment: What happens is that there winds up being a vertical spread in the data, when I phase it.  (This is, as I mentioned, light-curve data... so I have phased it from 0 to 1.)  I would like to remove that vertical spread so that there is a cleaner appearance to the phased light-curve, but I can't do that until the non-linear trends are gone.

Comment: You don't have to post your actual code and data if you don't want to, but convention is that you have to give an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) -- otherwise other people have to spend time working up a test case to play with, the time you weren't willing to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a nutshell, you take the coefficients that `polyfit` returns and pass them to `polyval` to evaluate the polynomial at the observed "x" locations.

As a stand-alone example, let's say we have something similar to the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 10, num)
y = np.exp(x)

# Add some non-stationary noise that's hard to see without de-trending
noise = 100 * np.exp(0.2 * x) * np.random.normal(0, 1, num)
y += noise

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that I haven't used a polynomial function here to create `y`. That's deliberate. Otherwise, we'd get an exact fit and wouldn't need to "play around" with the order of the polynomial.

Now let's try detrending it with a 2nd order polynomial function (note the 2 in the line `model = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 10, num)
y = np.exp(x)

# Add some non-stationary noise that's hard to see without de-trending
noise = 100 * np.exp(0.2 * x) * np.random.normal(0, 1, num)
y += noise

# Detrend with a 2d order polynomial
model = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
predicted = np.polyval(model, x)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(x, y, 'ro')
axes[0].plot(x, predicted, 'k-')
axes[0].set(title='Original Data and 2nd Order Polynomial Trend')

axes[1].plot(x, y - predicted, 'ro')
axes[1].set(title='Detrended Residual')

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Notice that we didn't fit the data exactly. It's an exponential function and we're using a polynomial.  However, as we increase the order of the polynomial, we'll fit the function more precisely (at the risk of starting to fit noise):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]