# Detrend with mask Python

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I have a [file](https://ufile.io/txd70) which I read as follow:

```
data1 = np.loadtxt('lc1.out') 
x = data1[:, 0]
y = data1[:, 1]
```

[image: untreand]

I would like to detrend it and I found a very useful link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746297/detrend-flux-time-series-with-non-linear-trend).

```
model = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
predicted = np.polyval(model, x)
```

Anyhow, I would like to mask a part of the data such as I will fit using only points outside the mask. For instance, I want to use only data lower than 639.5 and larger than 641.5 and the second-order polynomial fit.

I had the idea to use `ma.masked_outside(x, 639.5, 641.5)` such as it will be easy to save in an array only elements outside the mask...but I do not understand how to cast it with the `polyfit`.

Comment: While I think it may be just a typo, I'm not sure: The sample data you provided has only 2 columns, so attempting to extract 3 columns (`dmy`, `x`, `y`) from it will result in an `IndexError`. Did you mean `x = data1[:, 0]` and `y = data1[:, 1]` perchance? Please clarify. Also, is your lower bound of 639.5 deliberate? I can't see any x values below 640 in your sample data, so I'm a bit confused. I can only guess here, but if your intention was to exclude the anomaly in the middle, then maybe you wanted a lower bound of 640.5?

Comment: @blubberdiblub yes my mistake on the dmy, I will eliminate it, it was a dummy vector with no use in this example. 
The value around 639.5 was just an example but yes, the minimum value here is 640.  Actually, the point is to remove the 'linear' trend to have a normalized object without including in the calculation (mask) the anomaly at around  641. In this case, I have to take points let's say from 640 to 640.75 AND from 641.25 to 642, trim them and fitting those points. This was my idea to 'mask' the anomaly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might not be a hard reason to use masked arrays for your use case, unless it's for performance reasons or for making further use of the mask. So I'm going to show how to do it with and without a masked array.

But let's first detrend without masking in order to have a reference:

### Second order polynomial detrending without masking

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = np.loadtxt('lc1.out')
x, y = data1.T

fig = plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.title('polyfit, original data set')
plt.plot(x, y, 'c.')

coeff = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)

# no need to use the original x values here just for visualizing the polynomial
x_poly = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max())
y_poly = np.polyval(coeff, x_poly)
plt.plot(x_poly, y_poly, 'r-', linewidth=3)

mid = len(x_poly) // 2
plt.annotate('y = {:.7g} x\xB2 + {:.7g} x + {:.7g}'.format(*coeff),
             (x_poly[mid], y_poly[mid]), (0, 48), textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '->'}, horizontalalignment='center')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.title('detrended')

# we need the original x values here, so we can remove the trend from all points
trend = np.polyval(coeff, x)
# note that simply subtracting the trend might not be enough for other data sets
plt.plot(x, y - trend, 'b.')
fig.show()
```

[image: second order polynomial detrending without masking]

Take note of the coefficients of the polynomial.

### Second order polynomial detrending, selecting significant points

We can simply create new **x** and **y** arrays that contain only the wanted points. There is less potential for mistakes here.

This works in 3 steps. First we use a comparison operator on the array of interest, which results in a bool array with 'True' values at the indices where the comparison was true and 'False' values everywhere else.

Then we put the bool array through 'np.where()', which results in an array containing all the index numbers as values where the bool array had 'True' values, i. e. it's answering the question: "Where is my array truthy?"

And finally we peruse Numpy's advanced indexing and apply our result array of indices as index into both the **x** and **y** arrays, which filters out all unwanted indices.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = np.loadtxt('lc1.out')
x, y = data1.T
select = np.where((x < 640.75) | (x > 641.25))
x_selection = x[select]  # numpy advanced indexing
y_selection = y[select]  # numpy advanced indexing

fig = plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.title('polyfit, selecting significant points')
plt.plot(x_selection, y_selection, 'c.')

coeff = np.polyfit(x_selection, y_selection, 2)

# no need to use the original x values here just for visualizing the polynomial
x_poly = np.linspace(x_selection.min(), x_selection.max())
y_poly = np.polyval(coeff, x_poly)
plt.plot(x_poly, y_poly, 'r-', linewidth=3)

mid = len(x_poly) // 2
plt.annotate('y = {:.7g} x\xB2 + {:.7g} x + {:.7g}'.format(*coeff),
             (x_poly[mid], y_poly[mid]), (0, 48), textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '->'}, horizontalalignment='center')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.title('detrended')

# we need the original x values here, so we can remove the trend from all points
trend = np.polyval(coeff, x)
# note that simply subtracting the trend might not be enough for other data sets
plt.plot(x, y - trend, 'b.')
fig.show()
```

[image: second order polynomial detrending, selecting significant points]

The coefficients are different now, as expected.

### Second order polynomial detrending, masking unwanted points

Of course we can also use a masked array. Pay attention to the reversed logic: Masked points are those we **don't want**. As in the example data we don't want the points inside the interval, we use `ma.masked_inside()`.

If for performance reasons we want to avoid creating a full copy of the original array, we can use the keyword `copy=False`. Making the original array read-only saves us from accidentally changing the values in the masked array by mutating the original array.

For masked arrays we need to use the version of the `polyfit()` function from the `numpy.ma` submodule, which properly ignores the unwanted values both in the masked version of **x** as well as in the unmasked companion array **y**. If we fail to do that, we get wrong results. Note that this is an easy mistake to make, so we may want to stick to the other method if we can help it.

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = np.loadtxt('lc1.out')
x, y = data1.T
x.flags.writeable = False  # safety measure, as we don't copy
x_masked = ma.masked_inside(x, 640.75, 641.25, copy=False)

fig = plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.title('polyfit, masking unwanted points')
plt.plot(x_masked, y, 'c.')

coeff = ma.polyfit(x_masked, y, 2)

# no need to use the original x values here just for visualizing the polynomial
x_poly = np.linspace(x_masked.min(), x_masked.max())
y_poly = np.polyval(coeff, x_poly)
plt.plot(x_poly, y_poly, 'r-', linewidth=3)

mid = len(x_poly) // 2
plt.annotate('y = {:.7g} x\xB2 + {:.7g} x + {:.7g}'.format(*coeff),
             (x_poly[mid], y_poly[mid]), (0, 48), textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '->'}, horizontalalignment='center')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.title('detrended')

# we need the original x values here, so we can remove the trend from all points
trend = np.polyval(coeff, x)
# note that simply subtracting the trend might not be enough for other data sets
plt.plot(x, y - trend, 'b.')
fig.show()
```

[image: second order polynomial detrending, masking unwanted points]

The coefficients are the same as in the other method, which is good. Had we mistakenly used `np.polyfit()` instead, we would have ended up with the same coefficients as in the unmasked reference.